# My state didn't withdraw income tax from my paycheck.  What can I do about it?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax

I started a new job and today I received my first paycheck.  However, I noticed that the state (Utah in this case) didn't withhold income tax, even though the Federal withholding was applied. I asked about this and even my boss was surprised.  He told me that he had informed the state authorities about my employment and they were supposed to withhold income tax from my salary. He did it again and the state apparently refused to withhold income taxes.

Why is this happening? I am not necessarily a fan of paying taxes, but I don't want to pay a giant amount at the end of the year.

What can I do about it?

Comment: unless you work for the state, your employer is supposed to be collecting that tax, not the state. They have no access to your bank account or your company's.

Comment: I understand. I thought this is something the state collects personally.

Comment: Did you ever end up speaking with your company's accountant?  What did they tell you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In states which have an income tax and require withholding (like Utah), the employer which issues the pay check is responsible for deducting the tax from your pay and sending it to the state.  This is just like the procedure for U.S. federal taxes; the employer deducts the federal tax and sends it to the U.S. Treasury.

If you are employed in Utah, your employer is responsible for doing this.  The amount typically does depend on various factors, including the number of exemptions declared by you on your W-4 form, and can in some cases be zero.  (Even in that case, it is normal to have a deduction listed on your pay stub, just with a zero amount).  You need to check with your company's payroll department or pay accountant.